# Page freezes on Mobile after a single refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm testing on a webpage that displays a list of products, with photos, names, prices, etc. It works fine when I view it on my PC. When I visit the same page on mobile phones (Android and iPhone), the page freeze permanent.

[Website](https://runtimeterror.netlify.app/#)

Comment: I can access the webiste just fine. On mobile, the navigation bar works, but i can't scroll - Is this the problem you described? It also displays many errors, including 404 errors. So make sure you handle all the errors.

Comment: I found the bugs for the same. The problem is caused by jQuery, when I am removing the jQuery it starts working fine but on using jQuery it get freezes.

Comment: When inspecting your code, I get an error starting at `a.preventDefault()`. However, this error only occurs when the user starts scrolling. Also, this error occurs: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` for importing `pwaupdate`

Comment: Problem is with jQuery but don't know how to rectify the same